# XPath - Select First Child element regardless of parent

Tags: xpath

I have two XMl documents

```
<documentA xmlns="namespaceA">
   <IsSuccess>true</IsSuccess>
</documentA>

<documentB xmlns="namespaceB">
   <IsSuccess>true</IsSuccess>
</documentB>
```

I want to select the IsSuccess element regardless of what the parent node and namespace is

something like //IsSuccess?

Comment: Found the answer //*[local-name()='IsSuccess']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer xpath:  `//*[local-name()='IsSuccess']`